# Make an element's width the same as another element

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using rails-jquery-autocomplete gem here: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

The demo for the above gem is here: https://rocky-thicket-9286.herokuapp.com/

In my application, I need to make the autocomplete dropdown list width the same as the width of my input field which is a responsive component and has a width that varies.

How can I achieve this?

For example, can you show me how you will modify the example at https://rocky-thicket-9286.herokuapp.com/ so that its autocomplete drop down list width is the same as the width of its input field?

Is it possible to do this in pure CSS or JavaScript?

My current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var width = document.getElementById('search').offsetWidth;
  // won't work, document.getElementById('ui-id-1') gives null, but it shouldn't because I wait til window loaded as you can see below
  window.onload = document.getElementById('ui-id-1').style.width = width;
</script>
```

**Update 1**

As demonstrated by the image below, the width of the search field and the autocomplete drop down list are different:

[image: different width]

Comment: You could maybe take a look at css flexbox

Comment: not understand your problem. I can able to see both of them having same width in chrome.

Comment: Hi  Suresh Ponnukalai, please check out update 1

Comment: Hi, Simon, if I understand flex box correctly, it allows you to set the width of an element relative to other related element or the page. But in my case I want to set an element's width to be exactly the same as another unrelated (I guess it's not really related by dom tree structure except common parent element - body, so I call it unrelated) element. Their dom structure relationship can be seen in the demo link and right click > inspect in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turns out that a key element to the solution is documented in the [Gem's GitHub doc README page](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete#changing-destination-element). The first few time I read the doc I ignore this info because I misunderstood (thought of it as the input box, not the dropdown list but actually they are talking about the dropdown list).

Using the demo example at [the gems's doc page](https://rocky-thicket-9286.herokuapp.com/), after knowing the above information, you can place the autocomplete drop down list inside the form element and style the autocomplete's width to be 100%. The input box are under form element as well so now you should be able to have the same width for both the autocomplete input box and dropdown list. In HTML after erb processing, this means changing from this:

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="search-query" placeholder="namesearch" data-autocomplete="/foods/autocomplete_food_name">
```

to this:

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="search-query" placeholder="namesearch" data-autocomplete="/foods/autocomplete_food_name" data-append-to='search-form'>
```

since the element ID for the form element is 'search-form'.

In rails html.erb, this means changing from:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_food_name_foods_path %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_food_name_foods_path, append_to: '#search-form' %>
```

The css for the autocomplete dropdown list is:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the autocomplete dropdown list's width try to match its parent's (which is the form element)

The other element which is the autocomplete input field should already match parents, so now both autocomplete elements should have the same width.